# Make Custom Order Form Dynamic Using Apex and Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi I'm a newbie here in salesforce stackexchange, so please bear with me. :)

Assuming I have three custom objects: **Order__c**, **OrderItem__c**, and **Product__c**.

My plan is to create three sections in the Order Form (Order__c) and these are the sections: **Order Information**, **Delivery Information**, and **Product Information**. In the Product Information section, there's an Add button, and upon clicking this button, rows for adding products with corresponding quantity, unit price, discount (per product), and total price (per product) will appear.

Upon product selection and input of quantity and discount, Grand Total (From Order Information section) will automatically compute the total of the selected items in the Product Information Section. The idea is that before saving the order form, I will already have the idea of how much I'm going to pay for this transaction.

How can I do this without clicking New Button from Order Item, and there add product?

What I have right now is the usual process, meaning I'll have to save order first (without product info section). After the order form is saved, I'll have to look to OrderItem related list, and from there, add the products. This process takes much of my time, that's why I'm planning to have a new way.

Comment: Using standard layouts looks like that's the only option (create and the fill the related lists), another option is to build your own visualforce page. You can use as a the new layout or just add the visualforce page to the standard layout. It's just an option.

Comment: yes, that's what I did on the current process. sadly, I realized that it's not that very simple... I even searched through different tutorials, but I haven't found anything with same process. any way, thanks for your immediate response, I've really appreciated it :)

Comment: No problems at all. We are here to help...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using standard layouts looks like that's the only option (create and the fill the related lists), another option is to build your own visualforce page. You can use as a the new layout or just add the visualforce page to the standard layout. It's just an option.